# Can I increase the maximum number of indexes per collection in mongodb？

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection that has different query params to support,as such I create indexes for every keys. I just added a few more and get an error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: add index fails, too many indexes for collection key:{ foo: 1 }
```

and then I notice that the maximum number of indexes per collection in mongodb is just 64, Can I change this number ?

Comment: Nah it is hardcoded, why do you need so many indexes? it does kind of defeat of the point of indexes having that many

Comment: @Sammaye, 64 is not that many if you have a primarily read-only/search-only collection with a lot of properties or even indexes on nested properties.

Comment: @SamuelNeff if that is teh case you should do what other people do which is logically denormalise, 90% chance that document will be terribly slow to load from disk, if yuo have 64 indexes on a single collection you are missing the point, you might as well just load your entire colleciton into ram

Comment: @Sammaye, denormalize makes it flatter which would be even more indexes per collection, right?

Comment: @SamuelNeff no logical denormalisation in the sense I speak of is to separate tables to make them faster to query by making them smaller.

Comment: @SamuelNeff At the end of the day if you are using 64 indexes per collection there is a good chance you should be using an in memory database

Comment: @Sammaye, sorry, I'm new to Mongo, isn't that "normalization"??

Comment: @SamuelNeff No that is normalissed form, imagine taking a large normalised table and just splitting it down the middle to make the table smaller to access, that is what many larger sites do even with SQL

Comment: @SamuelNeff I mean the write throttling you will get on this collection alone would be crazy for any significantly large collection with even the most base indexes let alone complex ones, though if it is read only that does mitigate it

Comment: @Sammaye, isn't splitting a collection/table up for performance 'sharding', not 'normalization'/'denormalization'?

Comment: @SamuelNeff No sharding is housing a range of data for a collection, I mean splitting a table into equal columns and actually storing two different tables. Sorry I keep using vague English

Answer (score 8):

The max is built into MongoDB:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

> **Number of Indexes per Collection**
>
> A single collection can have no more than 64 indexes.

Comment: Is there a way to change those limits? My Mongo database servers all run on PCIe Ramdrives, and have 1TB of RAM each. We have one collection with a million records that gets searched each of 20 different ways 100 times a second (ecommerce site).

This post is about numbers of indexes, but there's also a limit of indexing size per collection. Changing the limits would apply to what I need also. Does anyone know a way to increase limits? We would be willing to fork and compile our own MongoDB if needed.

Comment: @JohnGalt I would probably use kinesis to duplicate the data across multiple collections where each collection can have its own indexes specific to each individual query pattern.

Comment: It should be noted that even though this answer is 9 years old at this point it is still correct. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#indexes